# Is $g$ integrable, given $f$ integrable and $g=f$ except for a set of Lebesgue measure 0 (not necessarily finite)?

Tags: analysis, riemann-integration

If $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$, and the value of $g$ agrees with $f$ at almost every point (except on a set of Lebesgue measure 0), is it true that $g$ Riemann integrable and $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$?

I have managed to show that if $f$ and $g$ are both integrable and their values agree at almost every point (except on a set of measure 0), then $\displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} g(x) dx=\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx$. However, I wonder if we have to assume that $g$ is integrable or we can derive it with the integrability of $f$. If not, what would be a counter-example?

Comment: No it's not true (take $f=0$ and $g=\boldsymbol 1_{\mathbb Q}$). Nevertheless, $g$ is Lebesgue integrable and $\int_{[a,b]}^{\mathcal L} g=\int_{[a,b]}^{\mathcal R} f.$ (where $\int^{\mathcal L}$ is the lebesgue integral and $\int^{\mathcal R}$ is the Rieman integral).

Comment: @Surb Thank you!!!

Comment: @Surb I think I wrongly assumed the set of difference to be closed, while a measure 0 set is not necessarily closed~ If the set of difference is closed and measure 0, then the point of discontinuity will also have measure 0, which implies the integrability of $g$.